# In gtest, can you try/catch a function that calls "exit(1)"?

Tags: c++, googletest

There's a function that calls `exit(1)` for specific cases, and I'm trying to run unit tests with gtest on that function.

I thought I'd be able to use try/catch for that case where the function calls `exit(1)`, but it doesn't catch for me.

Is this normal behavior? If so, how else should I detect that `exit(1)` was called?

Comment: exit() doesn't throw an exception, it causes the program to terminate normally. Why exactly do you want to detect it? You could potentially check for a specific exit code.

Comment: Try registering an atexit handler (note you cannot throw from it)

Answer (score 8):

Unlike in, say, Python, the `exit()` function of C and C++ doesn't work by throwing an exception.  Once it has done the C Runtime cleanup (e.g. calling registered `atexit()` handlers), it directly calls the kernel to terminate the process, and control never returns to the program.

The good news is that

### Google Test does support [testing for program exit](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#death-tests):

> ### `ASSERT_EXIT(statement, predicate, regex);` and `EXPECT_EXIT(statement, predicate, regex);`
>
> `statement` exits with the given error and its exit code matches `predicate`

I haven't checked, but I would guess that this is implemented by `fork()`ing the test, and waiting for the child to terminate.